# slidingtablayout doesn't work and has a lot of errors. why?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

The activity that leads to this activity has a button and on click it goes to this. It works fine without the tabs but when I put the tabs in it everything crashes!

**the activity**

```
 import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
    import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import com.example.hothyfa.comemyway.tabs.SlidingTabLayout;


    public class MainScreen extends ActionBarActivity {
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private SlidingTabLayout mtab;
    private ViewPager mpager;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_screen);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        mpager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);


        mpager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));

        mtab = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);

        mtab.setViewPager(mpager);


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main_screen, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "sittings clikced ...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            return true;
        }

        if (id == R.id.search) {

            Toast.makeText(this, "search clikced ...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        String tabs[];

        public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);

            tabs = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tabs);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {

            MyFragment myFragment = MyFragment.getInstance(position);
            return myFragment;
        }


        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return tabs[position];
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 3;
        }
    }


    public static class MyFragment extends Fragment {


        TextView textView;

        public static MyFragment getInstance(int position) {


            MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();

            Bundle argus = new Bundle();

            argus.putInt("postion", position);

            myFragment.setArguments(argus);

            return myFragment;

        }


        @Nullable
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my, container, false);

            textView = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.textView3);


            Bundle bundle = getArguments();
            if (bundle != null) {
                textView.setText(bundle.getInt("postion"));
            }

            return layout;


        }
    }


}
```

**the error**

```
08-10 09:24:18.416  12904-12904/com.example.hothyfa.comemyway E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.hothyfa.comemyway, PID: 12904
    android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
            at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:299)
            at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4132)
            at com.example.hothyfa.comemyway.MainScreen$MyFragment.onCreateView(MainScreen.java:153)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1789)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:955)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1138)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:740)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1501)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:490)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1105)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:951)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1473)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
            at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:124)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5535)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2615)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17547)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2015)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1173)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1379)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1061)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5885)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java
08-10 09:24:18.488  12904-12916/com.example.hothyfa.comemyway I/art﹕ Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 1001(191KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 32% free, 1047KB/1559KB, paused 6.827ms total 74.586ms
```

**my xml file**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.hothyfa.comemyway.MainScreen">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        layout="@layout/app_bar"/>

    <com.example.hothyfa.comemyway.tabs.SlidingTabLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager

        android:id="@+id/pager"



        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"


        />



</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: improve formatting and correct spelling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change
 `textView.setText(bundle.getInt("postion"));`

line to

`textView.setText(String.valueOf(bundle.getInt("postion")));`

Comment: 'i was waiting the 9 min'